# Ignore snippets in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2

I want ignore some snippets in specific Project, for example:

- I have Laravel and CodeIgniter snippets, but the opened project is in CakePHP, so I want disable some snippets.

Obs.:

- Laravel snippets is not a Package/Plugin. I created them, then I want to tell the name (or tab trigger) which snippets wich to disabled in this project.

How can I do that?

---

- Sublime Text 2
- Windows 7 Professional / Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Can you expand on what you are asking or clarifying.  It is not clear what you are asking.  Maybe give an example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot selectively disable snippets based on name or trigger.

If they are your own snippets, I would create a subfolder in `Packages/User`. Name this folder something meaningful to you, but that does not have the same name as any existing package. Place all of the relevant snippets in that folder. Finally, create a project specific setting ignoring that package (the name of the subfolder you created).